Need help designing a 27 MHz antenna
I am brand new to StackExchange and I was wondering how should I design an 27 MHz antenna for my DIY 27 MHz transmitter.
Unfortunately, the height of 1/4 wavelength antenna doesn't come into the consideration because it would be too long for my handheld transmitter. I was looking through different antenna types and came across a simple coil-shortened antenna.
My design parameters are that the antenna should be 0.5m tall in relation to my ground plane and it should be matched properly (without the complex part of the impedance). I was also wondering if I could just wind a 2.78 m long wire like an inductor and make the antenna that way (I am guessing that the impedance will be complex that way). Also, how should I predict the radiation resistance of the antenna. As you can see, I am a bit lost and any help would be appreciated.

Hi Andrej, welcome here. Please state the bandwidth of the antenna you want to build! Building an antenna that has 10% of its center frequency as bandwidth (so, for example, 27 MHz +- 5%, i.e., 25.65 MHz to 28.35 MHz) is much easier than one that has 50%. Building an electrically small antenna with 10% bandwidth is already challenging, but 1% might be quite doable. So, what's the lowest and highest frequency you need your antenna to work well at?

but one question I can already address here: no, just coiling a piece of a defined length doesn't give you the short version of the monopole antenna of that length. Simply not how that works :)

If a resonant antenna isn't feasible, you could use really fat wires to make a smaller but high BW dipole and use a tuned amplifier(s) in your reciever. Might need additional filtering though.

Hi Marcus, the bandwidth would be fairly small in comparison to the carrier frequency; Bw=270kHz, (26.865MHz-27.135MHz). Or +-1% of the carrier.
